# Plural or singular tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

roguelike or roguelikes?

shooter or shooters?

Answer (score 3):

Suggested rule:

- Platforms should remain singular: iphone, xbox, mac, pc.

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to ask this.

From [a related meta.SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags), my favorite comment was "Common sense, please. Keywords should not be pluralised. Concepts probably should. And certain words need to be left alone because pluralising them would change the meaning."

I'm going to post some suggested guidelines, one-at-a-time -- so people can upvote only the concepts they agree with.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested rule:

For Genres, It Depends.

- Some seem obviously singular (to me): "strategy", "turn-based-strategy", "fps".
- Some genres get pluralized in common speech, and should be left that way: "roguelikes", "shooters"

**Rule of thumb:**
If you append "games" to the plural form of a genre, then make it singular.

- "Strategy games" -> "strategy"
- "Shooters"
- "Roguelikes"
- "Massively Multiplayer Games" -> "mmorpgs"
- "Flight Simullators" -> "flight-simulators"